# ABCPDF links are highlighted in dark color

Tags: html, abcpdf

I'm using ABCPDF.Net version 5 to create a PDF file from HTML. However, the links appear to be highlighted in a dark color and almost impossible to read. If I set pdfDoc.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = false; then the text displays fine but obviously the links are gone. The links also display fine as HTML. Just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before, or has an idea about how to fix.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Version 5 is very old. I would recommend that you upgrade to the latest version, it has a much better render engine for HTML.

ABCPdf will stream in what ever the HTML looks like on the server. First off double check that you are not getting this issue when you view the HTML direct on the server. open the page in IE (ABCPdf, pre version 8 uses the servers version of IE for the render).

If you are getting the links a funny colour on the server, just change the css of the page until it all looks ok.